# Linux: list all matches in 'which' command

Tags: linux

'man which' says:

```
   --all, -a
       Print all matching executables in PATH, not just the first.
```

But when I do that, I get:

```
> which --all g++
--all: Command not found.
/usr/bin/g++
> which -a g++
-a: Command not found.
/usr/bin/g++
```

Tried placing --all or -a after "g++" too, no luck.

Comment: Which system and version are you using?  My Ubuntu 14.04 based system has a `which` command with ONLY "`-a`" (there is no "all" option).  And, it works just fine.

Comment: I just tried both syntaxes on Gentoo and Centos 6 in bash and they all worked fine.  `which -v` could perhaps clarify the issue, also mentioning your shell could give hints.

Comment: My build of which doesn't do that. So yeah, I gotta echo that, this is specific to the build you're running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `tcsh` shell, which has a *built-in* version of `which`.

<sup>(Note the `>` prompt and the error message style.)</sup>

Use `/bin/which -a …` or `/usr/bin/which -a …` to invoke GNU which.